# Pivot table not worked by dynamic parameter

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, pivot-table, dynamicquery

I wrote this query:

```
declare @startdate nvarchar(10) = '2016/01/01',
        @enddate nvarchar(10) = '2019/10/04',
        @cols nvarchar(max),
        @strsql nvarchar(max);

select 
    @cols =
    (select distinct QUOTENAME(maintenancename)+','
       from (select distinct maintenancename 
          from Table_maintenancetype where coalesce(maintenancename, '') != '') AS t1   
       for xml path('')    
    ) 
set @cols=LEFT(@cols,LEN(@cols)-1)

set @strsql=N'select *
from
(select sum(timedurationok) as wt, maintenancetype,tcode
            from Table_maintenancereport    
            where ((svok=1 and need_netok=0) or (svok=1 and netok=1 and need_netok=1))and tcode<>-1
            and dateendrole >='+ @startdate+ 'and dateendrole<='+ @enddate+'
            group by maintenancetype,tcode
) d 
pivot
(sum(wt)
for maintenancetype in ('+@cols+')
) piv
'

exec sp_executesql @strsql
```

When execute this no record return but when replace `@startdate` and `@enddate` by '2016/01/01','2019/10/04'

The query works fine I don't know what the problem is... and when use between in query I get error for can not convert nvarchar to data int 2016

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! `@startdate` and `@enddate` are **clearly** dates - so you should **NOT** declare them as `nvarchar(10)` - use `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, do a `print @strsql` to show your dynamic query and check.

You will see that your query is `dateendrole >= 2016/01/01`

the date should be in single quote `dateendrole >= 2016/01/01'`

your query should be

```
and dateendrole >= '''+ @startdate+ ''' and dateendrole<= '''+ @enddate+'''
```

a better way is to use parameter with `sp_executesql`

declare both the variable as `date` data type since it is going to hold date value

```
declare @startdate date = '20160101',
        @enddate   date = '20191004'
```

and in your dynamic query, just use the variable

```
and dateendrole >= @startdate and dateendrole <= @enddate
```

finally when calling `sp_executesql`, pass in the variable. And don't forget to print out the verify your query

```
print @strsql
exec sp_executesql @strsql, N'@startdate date, @enddate date', @startdate, @enddate
```

Comment: Any answer that tells someone to stop (insecurely) injecting a parameter in a query gets a +1 from me.